# Dynamic pivot by year month concatenated

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following data in a table. There will be many `LocationID` and for  each location, there will be 120 months (fixed 10 years) of data.

| LOC | Yr | Mon | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023 | 4 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 5 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 6 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 7 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 8 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 9 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 10 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 11 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023 | 12 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2024 | 1 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2024 | 2 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2024 | 3 | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2024 | 4 | 34.12 |
| 101 | 2024 | 5 | 34.12 |
| 101 | 2024 | 6 | 34.12 |

I'm trying to get it in a format like the following (ascending year-month order):

| LOC | 2023-Apr | 2023-May | 2023-Jun | 2023-Jul | 2023-Aug | 2023-Sep | 2023-Oct | 2023-Nov | 2023-Dec | 2024-Jan | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 | 65.45 |  |

I got started with the following query to combine the date and month

```
SELECT 
    loc, CAST(yr AS varchar) + '-' + DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, Mon, -1)) [Period], 
    Amt
FROM 
    TBL 
WHERE 
    loc = 101 AND plID = 11
ORDER BY
    Yr, Mon
```

Which returns this result:

| loc | Period | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023-April | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023-August | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023-December | 65.45 |
| 101 | 2023-July | 65.45 |

Needing some help figure out the best approach to get the data from this to the desired format/layout that I mentioned in the second table above..

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following query which works. I had to put the data in a temp table as the CTE was not available in the second select (@query)! Also, the columns are not sorted in the way I want.

Suggestions?

```
SELECT loc, cast(yr as varchar) + '-' + DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,Mon,-1)) [Period], Amt into #TempTbl FROM TBL WHERE loc = 101 and plID = 11


DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    

            pivot 
            (
                 min(Amt)
                for Period in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
            
            
SELECT loc, cast(yr as varchar) + '-' + DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,Mon,-1)) [Period], Amt into #TempTbl FROM TBL WHERE loc = 101 and plID = 11


DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Period]) 
            FROM #TempTbl c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT LOC, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select LOC
                    , Amt
                    , [Period]
                from #TempTbl
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 min(Amt)
                for Period in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: you can add the sort to your FOR XML path thing